# How to create random dataframe with positive numbers only?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create random DataFrame with positive numbers only.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4),
               index=pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=5),
               columns=['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta'])
print (df)
```

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
               Alpha      Beta     Gamma     Delta
2012-01-01  0.817239  0.004713 -0.661963 -0.464963
2012-01-02 -2.255352 -0.064958  0.646194 -0.952761
2012-01-03  0.164314  0.177159 -1.618655  0.210663
2012-01-04 -0.231917 -0.627284  1.722947 -0.497787
2012-01-05 -0.214804  0.952356  0.816623 -1.576765
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the distribution you want?  I mean, you could simply use `abs(df)` and fold the negative numbers positive, but then you don't have a normal distribution anymore.  You could use a uniform random distribution and specify limits, etc., etc.,

Comment: What distributions do you want your random numbers to be drawn from? Maybe you do not want Gaussian distribution but Uniform?

Comment: 1 to 10.....Not gaussian distribution

Comment: @I'-'I  Perfect!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.random.rand()`  produces a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.

> Create an array of the given shape and populate it with
>   random samples from a uniform distribution
>   over `[0, 1)`.

For a 5x4 uniform distribution array between 1 to 10,

```
np.random.rand(5,4)*9+1
```

If you just want integers between 1(incl) and 10(excl)

```
np.random.randint(1,10,(5,4))
```